# How to keep user data in text box of a form

Tags: php, html

I am using the current code

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
<tr>
<td>Enter joker number:</td>
 <td align="center"><input type="text" VALUE="<?php $joker ?>" name="joker" 
 size="3" maxlength="3"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit Order"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['joker'])){
$joker = $_POST['joker'];}
?>
```

For the data entry of a form. Since this saves data as `$joker` in the php portion of my code, I was hoping that `<?php $joker ?>` would allow the previous data to be left on screen, but it didn't work. Any idea on how to refine my code?

Comment: Isn't that putting the value of $joker into the textbox, rather than saving the textbox's value into $joker?

Comment: you should at least reply to the answer given to you that it solved your problem or not..

Answer (score 0):

Use your original code but move the php section above the HTML form code. And add echo in the embedded php directive.

Also set $joker as empty string or anything default at the top of the php code.

```
<?php 
$joker = "";
if(isset($_POST['joker'])){
$joker = $_POST['joker'];}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
<tr>
<td>Enter joker number:</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" VALUE="<?php echo $joker; ?>" name="joker" size="3" maxlength="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit Order"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write only `echo` in php code before `$joker`. Thats it.
Do like following:

```
<input type="text" VALUE="<?php echo $joker ?>" name="joker" 
 size="3" maxlength="3">
```